# Regular Expression with letter

Tags: python, regex, format, expression

I need to match things that format something along the lines of 
657432-76,   54678-01,   54364**A**-12

I got `(r'^\d{6}-\d{2}$')`
and   `(r'^\d{5}-\d{2}$')`
but how do you get the letter?

thanks!!

Comment: Combine them using `^\d{5,6}-\d{2}$` With optional letter its `^\d{5,6}[A-Z]?-\d{2}$`

Comment: Try [`^\d{5}(?:\d?|[A-Z])-\d{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/gE4cM8/1). Depends on what you actually mean. Another one - `^\d{5}\w?-\d{2}$`

Comment: @DavideVisentin: [it does](https://regex101.com/r/gE4cM8/2)

Comment: The only issue is whether the letter is only valid with a 5 digit preceding number. But why in the world would that be a criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single regex to match the 3rd pattern you can use a regex like this:

```
(?i)(r'^\d{5}[a-z]-\d{2}$')
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uA0bK2/1)**

However, if you want to have a single regex for all of them, you might find useful:

```
(?i)(r'^\d{5-6}[a-z]?-\d{2}$')
```

Keep in mind that this will allow: `657432A-76` but if you just want 5 digits only with the letter, then you could use:

```
(?i)(r'^\d{5}(?:\d?|[a-z])-\d{2}$')
```

Answer (score 0):

For the letter use `[a-zA-Z]`, and if it's only upper case then `[A-Z]` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the pattern generically is 6 characters with possible letter or number at last char max then `-` then 2 numbers? so then you'd use this pattern

`pattern = r'^d{5}.+-\d{2}$'`

Answer (score 0):

How about this expression:

```
>>> re.search(r'^\d+[A-Z]?-\d+$','657432A-76')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='657432A-76'>
>>> 
>>> re.search(r'^\d+[A-Z]?-\d+$','657432-76')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='657432-76'>
>>> 
>>> re.search(r'^\d+[A-Z]?-\d+$','65743-76')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 8), match='65743-76'>
>>>
```

Or if the format is as :

`[At most six digits][Possibility of a letter][-][At most two digits]`

Then:

```
>>> re.search(r'^\d{,6}[A-Z]?-\d{,2}$','65743A-76')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='65743A-76'>
>>> 
>>> re.search(r'^\d{,6}[A-Z]?-\d{,2}$','657436-76')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='657436-76'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible candidate matching all your samples:

```
import re

samples = [
    "657432-76",
    "54678-01",
    "54364A-12"
]

for s in samples:
    print re.match(r'^(\d+[A-Z]?)-(\d+)$', s).groups()
```